# Running Mac OS Tiger on Yosemite

Tags: virtualization, macos

How to run Mac OS Tiger on modern Mac? There’s a lot ways to launch Linux and Windows, but not an old Mac OS X. I’ve googled a lot and gave up to find a working solution.

*I need this to run specific software for my old but mighty film scanner.*

Comment: Virtualizing Mac OS X Tiger is not allowed by its SLA.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to install OS X Tiger on a modern Mac due to lack of hardware driver support.

Apple's license agreement for OS X did not allow virtualization at all until Snow Leopard Server and Lion, so virtualization software such as VirtualBox, VMWare Fusion, and Parallels Desktop do not support running Tiger in a Virtual Machine.

If you need to run Tiger, your best bet is purchasing an older Intel Mac that shipped with Tiger or a PowerPC Mac that supports Tiger.

Comment: I have old G4 for that purposes, but it’s very noisy and it’s inconvenient to switch between Macs. Anyway thanks for help, but it’s said there’s no way to virtualize an old OS X.